# Is the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission allowed for file sharing apps

Tags: android, android-permissions, storage-access-framework

I need some clarifications regarding the usage of the All Files Access(MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.
Is this allowed for file sharing apps where the user browse directories to select files in other to send? According to the new storage policy,with SAF,the system file picker can't be used to grant access to the root directory in android 11. That means,using the storage access framework,a user would have to open the system file picker,and grant access to each directory in the root path as it navigates through them,which would be totally inimical to user experience. I see such file sharing apps on playstore which were granted the permission. Thou I still would want to be sure I would be allowed to use the permission on my app before submitting it to playstore.

Comment: "the user browse directories to select files in other to send" - that is exactly what the Storage Access Framework allows users to do, all in one operation, returning the user selected files to your app so that you can send them anywhere you want.

Comment: Yes you can get this permission for file sharing apps https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files Because it fall in Device-to-device data migration category

Comment: @ianhanniballake in android 11 SAF,selecting the root path to grant access to it's subdirectories is no longer possible,hence a user would have to open the system file picker to   grant access anytime it wants to enter a directory of the root path.

Comment: @Ammar Abdullah Ok,thanks. Also,once I have the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission does it mean I'll be able to perform file operations on all the android versions using the `File` class API,and even have write access on SD card using them, which wasn't granted before?

Comment: Once you get MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission you will be able to perform file operation using File API on all Android levels. But for SD card I'm not sure but I think so there is a separate permission for reading and writing SD card.

Comment: You said you wanted the user to select _files_ to send. Users can select files in any directory via SAF, including in the root directory. Can you edit your question to explain how directories are related to what you are trying to do?